# Apply CSS transform scale without move other elements

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to grow the element background and font on hover. However it does impact all other elements position like the border of the form, elements side.
I tried to do it with the box-shadow but only the shadow is enlarged and not the text.

please Help

LINk: [Code for HTML and CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/xneogeo/4L0hnzqe/2/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

.contenedor {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

form {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 80px;
  background: #24b080;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #24b080;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #24b080;
  border: 2px solid #24b080;
  color: #fff;
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
```

```html
<form name="formulario" action="">
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
  <input type="submit" value="OK">
  <input type="submit" value="Cancel">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this

```css
form {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

to this:

```css
form {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 120px;
}
```

If you give the Form a fixed height then it cannot move when the buttons get bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `vertical-align: top;` to `input[type="submit"]` to avoid the slight vertical movement on hover (I guess that's what you meant?):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

.contenedor {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

form {
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 80px;
  background: #24b080;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #24b080;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  vertical-align: top;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #24b080;
  border: 2px solid #24b080;
  color: #fff;
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
```

```html
<form name="formulario" action="">
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
  <input type="submit" value="OK">
  <input type="submit" value="Cancel">
</form>
```